# Adding elements in Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array with the daily data like as below

```
Date           X
2010-01-01     15
2010-01-02     0
2010-01-03     30
```

I would like to disaggregate this daily data to hourly just by dividing each day data by 24. Is there any numpy built in function to do this.

I want something like this

```
 Date          X
 2010-01-01    0.6
 2010-01-01    0.6
 2010-01-01    0.6
 2010-01-01    0.6
 2010-01-01    0.6
 .......
 This for 24 times
 2010-01-02    0
 2010-01-02    0
 ....
```

Your suggestions are highly appreciated

Comment: Perhaps the easiest solution is `normalized_data = data[:, 1] / 24` and then do all calculations on `normalized_data` 24 times. Also, are you sure you have exactly a numpy array? The way you've formatted your example data makes me think it's actually a pandas data frame.

Comment: Thanks @ScottColby